# ASP.NET MVC Multi Tenant with seperated databases using Autofac and Owin

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac, multi-tenant

**Situation**

We have one ASP.NET MVC 5 application running along with SQL Server. We have one master database which contains a table `Tenants` where all of our tenants are registrated with a connection string property to their own personal database.

For authentication we are using the `Microsoft Owin` library.

**Autofac**

We have setup autofac like this:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Register the controllers
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(Project.Web.ProjectApplication).Assembly);

// ### Register all persistence objects

// Project main database registration ( Peta Poco instance using connectionstring as parameter )
builder.RegisterType<ProjectDatabase>()
    .As<ProjectDatabase>()
    .WithParameter(new NamedParameter("connectionString", GlobalSettings.ProjectTenantConnectionString))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

// Project tenant specific database registration
// ...

// Unit of work
builder.RegisterType<PetaPocoUnitOfWork>()
    .As<IDatabaseUnitOfWork>()
    .InstancePerRequest();

// ### Register all services
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("Project.Core"))
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

// ### Register all repositories
builder.RegisterType<RepositoryFactory>()
    .As<IRepositoryFactory>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("Project.Core"))
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

// Register Logging
builder.RegisterType<Logger>().As<ILogger>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

// Register Automapper
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("Project.Core")).As<Profile>();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("Project.Web")).As<Profile>();
builder.Register(context => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    foreach (var profile in context.Resolve<IEnumerable<Profile>>())
    {
        cfg.AddProfile(profile);
    }
})).AsSelf().SingleInstance();
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper(c.Resolve))
    .As<AutoMapper.IMapper>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

// Register Owin
builder.Register(ctx => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()).As<IOwinContext>();
builder.Register(
    c => new IdentityUserStore(c.Resolve<IUserService>()))
.AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();
builder.Register(
    ctx => ctx.Resolve<IOwinContext>().Authentication)
.As<IAuthenticationManager>().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<IdentityUserManager>().AsSelf().Inst‌​ancePerRequest();

// Build container
var container = builder.Build();

// Tenant container
var tenantIdentifier = new RequestSubdomainStrategy();
var mtc = new MultitenantContainer(tenantIdentifier, container);

// Set autofac as dependency resolver
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(mtc));
```

**More details**

Using this setup we have an instance setup in Autofac to our master `Tenant` database.
This is then injected into our `PetaPocoUnitOfWork` for committing the transaction.

This works, and I can get the tenant information.

But now we need the following to work and we don't have a clue where to start.

1. How do we setup autofac to register tenants peta poco database instances to inject into the `PetaPocoUnitOfWork` and how will the app now how to resolve this? Because we need to have access to 2 databases ( the master and the personal tenants database ), first for getting the tenants connection string and then for doing crud operations on the tenants database.
2. What about our `PetaPocoUnitOfWork`, which contains the database to work with, should we register this also per tenant and pass the database using the resolving method of autofac and set this on a instance per request?

Comment: Nice to see that already 3 SO users want to close this question... If its to broad should I place them in seperated questions and link them together or... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually have a shard manager [More similar to that of the Microsoft Azure Shard Manager] that takes the connectionstring name and the tenant context. From these information, it can resolve the connection and then pass it on to the Context.

This will be resolved on a per-tenant basis and then the application works with the tenant based connection, i.e. this is injected in each of the services so that the identity established [logged in user identity] could be used to set the right connection object in the EF / Data Tier. This way, it facilitates loose coupled design and also easy to test and mockup.

You can find sample code and little documentation of how such an implementation would look like from my [github repository](https://github.com/d-saravanan/multitenant.dev.template#database-sharding)

IMHO, the rationale behind this approach that I suggest would be the fact that the partitions per tenant would be stored in a database [typically your master database] and that would need to be fetched and used even if you are able to some-how inject these via Autofac. I did not reproduce the code here as it takes a bit long explanation to get the code and explanations here, which is being taken care in github.

HTH